# PATH enviromment variable in Android

Tags: android, path

I have a software composed by binary files and a main process in bash code. Is it possible to make that the install directory of the android .apk is add to PATH enviromment variable of the Android Device, so the software can be started in a terminal emulator? I must say that the final android device shouldn't be rooted.

Thank you!

Romili

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make that the install directory of the android .apk is add to PATH enviromment variable of the Android Device

No.